# Https causing too many redirects?

Tags: php, loops, redirect, https

I have a simple code in place for my php file to redirect to https if it's not present and I keep getting a too many redirects issue.

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {
redirect('https://domain.com/register.php');
}
```

Is there something I can do to fix the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a redirect on the page that it redirects to do you?

Comment: Nope, no other redirects.

Comment: The proper test is simply `!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])`. php doesn't guarantee a particular value, just that it's non-empty when SSL is in use.

Comment: what there is in the function `redirect` ?

Comment: Try: `print("HTTPS: ".$_SERVER['HTTPS']."\n");` What do you see?

Comment: what web server are you using? I tested on my web server (Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3) and it works fine (after defining a `redirect()` function)

Answer (score 3):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is `Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.` That isn't necessarily `on`. You may then end up in an infinite loop of redirects.

To avoid this, use the [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

```
if ((!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) || (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
    redirect('https://domain.com/register.php');
}
```

> **Note:** Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Hmm, so would

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
redirect('https://domain.com/register.php');
}

be the anwser?

Comment: @user1993382 If `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is empty, or not set, then the script was queried from a non HTTPS URL. So you may want to use `if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))` ...

Comment: @user1993382 I don't know the exact behavior of `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. The manual tells us `Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.`. But in case it isn't always set, you can also use: `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
 //redirect
}
```